# Sqlite Boolean and c# DataReader

Tags: c#, casting, sqlite, ado.net

Sorry, I have again a question about reading a sqlite db from c#.
Suppose you have a simple Boolean column in a table.
I want to use a .net DataReader (connected layer).
My question is:
Why I get a cast exception when calling the getBoolean method (solution A)?
Casting the DataReader to Boolean (solution B) works perfectly.

A) Boolean my_bool = DR.getBoolean(...

B) Boolean my_bool = (Boolean)DR[...

Obviously I can choose B but I would prefer the A programming style.
Thank you

Comment: Please do not deface your own post.

Comment: Rolled back again. Please show respect to future readers; this question might be useful to them. Deleting or defacing your question after you got an answer is not an accepted practice on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the data is most probably **not of type bool** when readed by the data reader.

The first snippet raises the `InvalidCastException`.
Second - retrieves the data of the other type and casts it locally to bool. CLR handles the cast and it works.

My guess is that your database returns integer values, `0` and `1` (bytes? shorts? ints?) so that casting works but trying to read boolean values just doesn't work.

To check this, log the readed value:

```
 Debug.Write( DR[...].GetType().ToString() );
```

Comment: This sounds related, I've just found it http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html "SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true)."

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in Sqlite Ado.net DataReader.

Refer to the thread linked [here](http://sqlite.org:8080/cgi-bin/mailman/private/sqlite-dev/2014-February/002295.html) in both sqlite-dev and sqlite mailing lists.

Possible work-around s are 1) implement a reliable column constraint with check in (0,1) to avoid the situation of 'Y' inserted instead of '1' (an issue of the old SqliteAdministrator)
2) defining a BOOLEAN_INT instead of BOOLEAN: when the ado.net does not automatically map to System.Boolean, then the DR recognizes any strings wrongly inserted

In any case , I confirm that the A programming style results safer.

Answer (score 0):

if the column is nullable, then you might be reading a DBNull object which will fail a cast to Boolean